# Pre install hook fails to run migrations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a pre-install hook to run migrations,
but my migrations fail on database connection refused.
How can I apply my network policy to the pre-install hook I created?

Comment: Are you sure it's a network policy issue and not a problem with misconfigured database hostname? Network policies differ depending on your CNI. Is your database running inside of the cluster? Do you have existing network policiies?

Comment: Yes, my database is running inside the cluster, and I can reach it from other pods, just not able from the pre-install pod. I do have existing network policies. thanks for your help!

Comment: which database you are using? there might be some other option instead of  using hook, as it does not wait for db to be up without doing some fancy stuff

Comment: Add config-map to your helm template with annotations for pre-install and weight lower than the hook (job/pod). If you have a sample config-map, add it to your question and I can use it to create an answer here.